# Why does the question not change, if Yes/ No is clicked? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio

The code below is based on a huge quiz I have made. (I have created this code, so it is shorter and thus clearer)

At the beginning an array list contains the Strings a, b, c and d and as the user presses a Button (yes/no) to a certain question, the question is supposed to switch and some of the strings are removed of the array list until there is only one possible string left.

My problem is that as I run the app, the question does not change, although I press Yes/no.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
static ArrayList<String> p = new ArrayList<String>(); 
static Button endbutton; 

static Button questionbutton; 
static Button yesbutton; 
static Button nobutton; 
static boolean yesbuttonisclicked=false; 
static boolean nobuttonisclicked=false; 
static boolean beginning=true; 
static int i=0; 

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

endbutton = findViewById(R.id.endbutton); 


questionbutton = findViewById(R.id.questionbutton); 
yesbutton = findViewById(R.id.yesbutton); 
nobutton = findViewById(R.id.nobutton); 
if (beginning) 
{ 
p.add("a"); 
p.add("b"); 
p.add("c"); 
p.add("d"); 
beginning = false; 
} 

yesbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) { 
yesbuttonisclicked=true; 
nobuttonisclicked=false; 
endbutton.setText("yes"); 
} 
}); 
nobutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) { 
nobuttonisclicked=true; 
yesbuttonisclicked=false; 
endbutton.setText("no"); 
} 
}); 

List array1 = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4"); 
Collections.shuffle(array1); 

if (array1.get(i) == "1") { 
questionbutton.setText("Question1"); 
if (yesbuttonisclicked) { 
p.remove("a"); 
p.remove("b"); 
yesbuttonisclicked=false; 
if (p.size() == 1) { 
endbutton.setText(p.get(0)); 
} 

} else if(nobuttonisclicked) { 
p.remove("c"); 
p.remove("d"); 
nobuttonisclicked=false; 
if (p.size() == 1) { 
endbutton.setText(p.get(0)); 
} 
} 
} else if (array1.get(i).equals("2")) { 
questionbutton.setText("Question2"); 
if (yesbuttonisclicked) { 
p.remove("a"); 
p.remove("c"); 
yesbuttonisclicked=false; 
if (p.size() == 1) { 
endbutton.setText(p.get(0)); 
} 
} else if(nobuttonisclicked){ 
p.remove("b"); 
p.remove("d"); 
nobuttonisclicked=false; 
if (p.size() == 1) { 
endbutton.setText(p.get(0)); 
} 
} 
} else if (array1.get(i).equals("3")) { 
questionbutton.setText("Question3"); 
if (yesbuttonisclicked) { 
p.remove("a"); 
p.remove("d"); 

yesbuttonisclicked=false; 
if (p.size() == 1) { 
endbutton.setText(p.get(0)); 
} 
} else if(nobuttonisclicked){ 
p.remove("c"); 
p.remove("b"); 
nobuttonisclicked=false; 
if (p.size() == 1) { 
endbutton.setText(p.get(0)); 
} 
} 
} else if (array1.get(i).equals("4")) { 
questionbutton.setText("Question4"); 
if (yesbuttonisclicked) { 
p.remove("d"); 
p.remove("c"); 

yesbuttonisclicked=false; 
if (p.size() == 1) { 
endbutton.setText(p.get(0)); 
} 
} else if(nobuttonisclicked){ 
p.remove("a"); 
p.remove("b"); 
nobuttonisclicked=false; 
if (p.size() == 1) { 
endbutton.setText(p.get(0)); 
} 
} 
} 
i++; 
} 
}
```

The problem should not be in pressing a button, as I have created an additional comment button in which I output yes if the yes button has been pressed and no if no button. So, this should not be the problem.

I just found out, that the program does not switch the booleans yesbuttonisclicked and nobuttonisclicked for some reason. That might be the mistake but I do not know how to fix it...

Comment: Maybe the mistake is on the warning "do not place android context classes in static fields" for the buttons? Does this matter?

Comment: (I have just proved it by cutting the variables into the oncreate and making them final instead static and it still does not work...)